# Mongoose bulkWrite loses data

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, bulkinsert

I try to use Model.bulkWrite(). The result showed me that all documents were updated (2567), but when I checked in db, I had only 2340 docs.

```js
    this.marketModel
      .bulkWrite(
        data.map((market) => ({
          updateOne: {
            filter: { code: market.code, exchangeCode: market.exchangeCode },
            update: market,
            upsert: true,
          },
        })),
      )
      .then((result) => console.log(result))
```

log result:

```json
BulkWriteResult {
  insertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 2568,
  modifiedCount: 2568,
  deletedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  upsertedIds: {},
  insertedIds: {}
}
```

I tried to split it into smaller chunks, but it also updated only 2340 docs.

It looks like mongoose loses data.

When I first time insert data in that way, it also loses data.

EDIT:
I based on the information that every object has unique constraints at exchangeCode and exchangeCode fields, but it wasn't true. So for future if someone get here, check 2 times your filter to be sure it's unique.